# java.math.BigDecimal does not always work for keeping two decimal places?

Tags: java

I am trying to find out several ways to keep two decimal places for double values. Currently, I tried the following 5 methods.

- Use java.math.BigDecimal
- Use java.text.DecimalFormat
- Use java.text.NumberFormat
- Use java.util.Formatter
- Use String.format

Result for these 5 methods are basically consistent. However, in some scenarios, java.math.BigDecimal has the different result with other 4 methods.

Take double value **100.0050D** for example:

**It returns 100.00 in my code when using java.math.BigDecimal. However the other 4 methods return 100.01. The result is inconsistent.**

Actually, **RoundingMode.HALF_UP** is used. Here comes my question:

**Is there anything I missed for using java.math.BigDecimal to keep two decimal places with double value in my code below ?**

**or is it a tiny flaw in class java.math.BigDecimal?**

Please help me out with this. Thank you in advance.

In addition, I am not sure whether it differs in various JDK versions, just provide information that the version of JDK I used is **1.7.0_25**.

Code is as follows:

```
public final class PrecisionTest {

    private PrecisionTest() {
    }

    public static String format1(double value) {

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.toString();
    }

    public static String format2(double value) {

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return df.format(value);
    }

    public static String format3(double value) {

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
        return nf.format(value);
    }

    public static String format4(double value) {
        return new Formatter().format("%.2f", value).toString();
    }

    public static String format5(double value) {

        return String.format("%.2f", value).toString();
    }
}
```

Simple test code is as follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {   

        double[] testData = new double[] { 100.123D, 1234567.897D, 100.0050D,   
                80.0051D,-100245.3658D};   

        for (double value : testData) {   
            System.out.println(PrecisionTest.format1(value));   
            System.out.println(PrecisionTest.format2(value));   
            System.out.println(PrecisionTest.format3(value));   
            System.out.println(PrecisionTest.format4(value));   
            System.out.println(PrecisionTest.format5(value));   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: do you mean BigDecimal instead of BigInteger ?

Comment: Yes. It is about java.math.BigDecimal not java.math.BigInteger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double representation of 100.005 isn't exact, and is slightly less than 100.005:

```
scala> new java.math.BigDecimal(100.0050)
res0: java.math.BigDecimal = 100.0049999999999954525264911353588104248046875
```

So when you set the scale and rounding mode, it gets rounded down to 100.00.

On the other hand, constructing a BigDecimal using a String works as expected:

```
scala> new java.math.BigDecimal("100.0050")
res2: java.math.BigDecimal = 100.0050

scala> res2.setScale(2, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString
res3: java.lang.String = 100.01
```

Answer (score 2):

> double[] testData = new double[] { 100.123D, 1234567.897D, 100.0050D,
>                   80.0051D,-100245.3658D};

The problem is here. Nothing to do with BigDecimal at all. These numbers cannot be represented accurately in floating-point. Try initialising your BigDecimal from *String* representations of the values.